# How to add new user to api data react js

Tags: reactjs, authentication, post

I've been working on small user managment app. My task is get data from api(fetch or axios), show that data on browser, search for the user and create a signup form. I have done almost everything, but I have a problem with signup form.

My problem is when I add information in signup form and press submit, new user isnt created. Do I use a put request with api and how to concatenate to the existing list.

this is my Login.js:

```
import React, {Component}  from 'react'; 
import axios from 'axios';

class Login extends Component{
    constructor() {
        super();
    this.state = {
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        occupation: ''
    };
}
changeHandler= (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}   

submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.state)
    axios.post('https://reqres.in/api/users?per_page=20', this.state)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}
 render() {
    const {first_name, last_name, occupation} = this.state;
    return(
        <form onSubmit ={this.submitHandler}>
            <label >first_name</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" 
                onChange={this.changeHandler}
                value={first_name} />

            <label>last_name</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" 
                onChange={this.changeHandler} 
                value={last_name} />

            <label>occupation</label>
            <input type="text" name="occupation" 
                onChange={this.changeHandler}
                value={occupation} />

            <button
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn-primary">Save
            </button>
        </form>
    )
}
}
export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to their [official docs](https://reqres.in/) reqres.in requires you to send a post request to `/api/users`.

[image: Create endpoint]

Note that in their example they don't use query parameters for the post request, as their request looks like this:

[image: Request format]

Make sure the data that is contained by the current state actually contains the values you expect it has (you pass in `this.state` as the data object). To find out what's in your state before sending the request, you may

- write a `console.log(this.state)` before the axios.post method runs
- trigger the `submitHandler` by clicking the button.

If you are sending data, but the user is still not created, the API will probably give you a response with a code. To find this, you may;

- open the network tab of your browser before triggering the `submitHandler`.
- click the button to trigger the `submitHandler`
- click on the resulting `request` in your network tab
- look at the `response`, it's `response code` and its `error message`

This information should give you sufficient context to figure out the problem.